# Do we need a separate "preparation" tag apart from "planning"?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

I just noticed [a new question about Yosemite](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3037/how-to-prepare-for-a-trip-to-the-half-dome-in-yosemite-national-park) includes a new tag [preparation](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/preparation).

Seems like another case where yeah the words are not exact synonyms but the same types of questions would tend to get either tag so splitting questions into one tag or the other might be unnecessary and not really helpful in the long run.

Then again "preparation" could be seen as including planning so maybe it's a better main tag if the two become synonyms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Done. [preparation](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/preparation) is now a synonym of [planning](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/planning). Probably a case of a person typing in whatever popped first into their head. I don't see any semantic difference in what the two tags can mean.

Answer (score 4):

I think preparation or planning is enough. We don't need both. I just didn't saw the already existing tag planning and so I used preparation.

Comment: No problem. It might be better than planning anyway (-: A tip though: I always type the first couple of letters and wait to see what tags are suggested. Then again I'm a bit of a tagging-nerd...

Comment: Yes I know this. But the problem is you first have to think about all possible tags. If you don't know that there exists a tag planning you don't enter p ;)

Comment: Now this is exactly whey synonyms are good!! I seem to have trouble convincing people of this sometimes. But in this case they both start with "p" d-;